# Error in OleControl causes JVM to crash completely - how to suppress?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, ole

I have some serious problem. We have in our application plugged in an external ole plugin in our eclipse rcp client. This plugin causes some error while running, which then kills the entire client.

Since we cannot fix the problem, we want to catch that error, so that the client at least won't crash. To be more precise, the client crashes because the JVM caused a fatal error. Is there any possibility to suppress those errors, to avoid the JVM from crashing?

This is the code where we include the plugin in our client, has anyone some idea how to achieve such a error-catch?

```
    // create OLE frame and site (XMAX control).
    clatFrame = new OleFrame(parent, SWT.NONE);
    clatUtil = null;
    try {
        clatSite = new OleControlSite(clatFrame, SWT.NONE,
                "Congree.XMax.Control");
        clatSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);
        clatUtil = new OleUtil(clatSite);

        // setzt die Dialogsprache
        String dialogLanguage = Platform.getNL();
        // Umgehung für Bug-20760
        if (LOCALE_DE.equalsIgnoreCase(dialogLanguage)) {
            // ClatIn Format 'de-DE'
            dialogLanguage = dialogLanguage + "-DE"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        } else {
            dialogLanguage = dialogLanguage.replace("_", "-");
        }

        clatUtil.invokeMethod(null, "SetGuiLanguage", true, dialogLanguage);

        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().hint(SWT.DEFAULT, 25).grab(true,
                false).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP).applyTo(clatFrame);
    } catch (SWTException e) {
        clatFrame.dispose();
        LOG.warn("OLE control (CLAT) not installed");
    }
```

LOG

http://www.file-upload.net/download-8284055/jvm_errorlog.log.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to catch the Throwable instead of the SWTException. If that doesn't help, you can try a different library like jacob for the OLE/COM automation: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/ The crash is most likely caused by some invalid state in the c code, therefore a different library might help.

Comment: We of course already tried to catch Exception. Without success :( I am looking at the jacob library, thank you